# Detecting Client Aborting XHR on Django Server

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, sockets

I have a server which dispatches some long running jobs when a client spawns a request.  Since these jobs are long running and particularly resource heavy, I want a way to kill the processes related to the client's request on the server side when the client aborts their XHR.  Another important thing to note is that all these long computations are done within this one user request (eventually I'd like to move to a polling system involving Celery, but that's for the future).

I'm using JQuery's AJAX extension, and I have a button on my frontend which aborts the AJAX request when clicked.  This button just calls xhrJQ.abort().  As far as I can tell, the only potentially observable xhrJQ.abort() does is close the socket the client is listening on, though I'm not certain this is even true.  I'm using Django, so I can get the address and port the client is requesting from through the HTTPRequest object Django passes.  But I'm not sure 1) whether my assumption about xhrJQ.abort closing the socket is true 2) if it is true how to detect a client's closing a socket.

I've looked around quite a bit and haven't been able to find a way to easily see if a client cancelled their request other than building a way to communicate these things between the server and client myself (using a polling system involving Celery for example).  Does anyone have any tips or recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no built in way to know if a request was cancelled on the client from the server. It's analogous to trying to tell by the bullet fired whether the gun still exists. The only way would be to send another request when the user cancels the request which cancels the long running process. Obviously for this to work, you'd need some method of identifying each running process per user.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I just was hoping there was an easier way to go about figuring this out.  Though I do wonder one thing still.  Say I could figure out what the socket was that the client was listening for the response from.  Why couldn't I listen on that socket of the client's for a close event?  Even if I could do this I probably wouldn't, I'd prefer something cleaner, but I'm wondering if it isn't possible and why it isn't possible if so.